# Can I print an image and set it to scale-to-fit on a page?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, printing, photoshop-elements

I'm using Adobe Photoshop Elements and I need to make a few tweaks to an image that is quite large but will be scaled and printed on a document from another application (Crystal Reports, if you must know.)

I need to make changes to my image and I'd like to actually print the image out from within Photoshop Elements as a preview.  The problem is that the image is really large and scales across multiple pages.

Is there some setting that I can change that will force the image to be scaled to fit within a standard document?

I can't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple in Photoshop Elements.  With any image in PSE, just click print and check the box "Scale to Fit Media" in the print dialog as shown below...

[image]

Be sure to set your paper size first.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, but my version of Elements was different.  Specifically, the Scaling option was buried in another window, from the Print... dialog.  Thanks for the help, though.  This confirmed to me that the option had to be available, some where.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great with printers or printing, but couldn't you create a new document in Photoshop with the "U.S. Paper" preset and then import your image onto that document, and then print? It should be scaled on the paper just as it is on the new document, then.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are mentioning.  What I want to do is be able to make minor tweaks, to an unsaved imaged, and  then preview the tweaks on a piece of paper.  In order to do this, I need to rescale the image when it prints.  I'd rather not have to go back and forth creating new files/documents each time I want to do a test print, since I may have to make a moderate number of alterations.

Comment: Also, thank's for trying.  I figured I'd through you a few rep points for trying.

Comment: Couldn't you import your image, as a Smart Object, onto a document that fits a page, and then make edits to the Smart Object? You can edit the image by itself, and as you edit it, the changes are reflected onto the document that fits the paper. Then, you can print and preview the changes.

Comment: No need to go through those multiple steps.  The OP said the image is already open in Photoshop Elements.  It's just three clicks to print the image properly scaled to fit any paper size he might use.

Answer (score -1):

Save the image as a jpeg, png, or something similar, and then open the image using Windows Photo Viewer and click print on the top menubar:
[image]

It will give you various scaling options in the dialog box, including scale to fit to page:

[image]

Comment: Why go through another program? Photoshop Elements does that exact same thing.

Comment: It's going through Windows, basically. I don't have PSE on hand and while I suspect that it probably does, it does help by keeping your workflow in PSE separated from these preview printouts. I was operating under the assumption that PSE had an easy way to go about doing it, per the OP.